# Mercurial on Windows: abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a Mac and Windows 7 PC where Mercurial/BitBucket work as expected.  However, I just created a new Windows 7 VMWare Fusion image and I get the following error if I try to clone over https.

`abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Is there something about the Virtual Machine that breaks it?  I installed Mercurial/TortoiseHG the same way on the physical Win7 box and on the VMWare image.

Is there some way to get more information on the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that entering bad information in the [http_proxy] section of mercurial.ini interferes with http communication. Wish I would have double-checked that two days ago!