# HG PUSH : abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I am trying to push my changeset and after halting for a long time, I am getting this error message:

abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I am using Apache on windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured an `[http_proxy]` somewhere by any chance?

E.g. in your `.hgrc` or a tortoise `mercurial.ini`? This has been other people's [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554921/mercurial-on-windows-abort-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-b).

Other people have reported the [problem](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/220/unable-to-connect-to-connect-to-mercurial) for Mercurial 2.0 but as working fine in Mercurial 1.

Comment: No I have not defined in any of these files.

Comment: What Mercurial version do you have?

Comment: hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.0.2)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Well I would try going back a version (if that's not going to break too much for you), and see if that works. Maybe version 1.9, or even version 1.5. I know that doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Comment: And you've never had Tortoise installed? It could still have your mercurial.ini file lying around. Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Actually I would try going forward a couple of versions. Mercurial 2.3.1 has been released, and 2.0.2 is now well over half a year old. There’s a good chance your issue may have been fixed by a newer release.